# C Inserting characters into 2D array in distance from defined position

Tags: arrays, c

I need to "draw" by inserting characters into the 2d array in a given range from specified position.

So, I'm placing letter 'A' in matrix, position i.e. 7,7. I would like to draw 'x' letters from the 'A' letter - four left and four right, and then one step a line up, the x just above the A, three X's left and three right, again step up, two X's left and two right and again. The same down.

Sounds simple but I'm failing to do it, I need some help here. Looks like I'm doing something wrong in the first loop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char matrix[14][22];
int i,j,ran;
int range = 4;
int posx = 7;
int posy = 7;

void draw_range(void){
    for (ran=range;ran>=0;ran--){
        /* drawing range to the right side */
        /* up */
        for(i=0;i<=ran;i++) {
            if (matrix[posy-i][posx+range-ran] == '.'){
                matrix[posy-i][posx+range-ran] = 'x';
            }
            /* down */
            if (matrix[posy-i+ran][posx-ran+range] == '.'){
                matrix[posy-i+ran][posx-ran+range] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
    /* drawing range to the left side */
    for (ran=0;ran<range;ran++){
        /* down */
        for(i=range;i>0;i--){
                if (matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] == '.'){
                    matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
                }
                /* up */
                if (matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] == '.'){
                    matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
                }
            }
        }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    // fill array with spaces
    for (i=0;i<14;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<22;j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    // put symbol to arrat
    matrix[posy][posx] = 'A';

    draw_range();

    // print array
    for (i=0;i<14;i++) {
        for (j=0;j<22;j++) {
            printf("%c",matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Compiling with: `gcc main.c -o main`.

Desired output:

```
......................
......................
......................
.......x..............
......xxx.............
.....xxxxx............
....xxxxxxx...........
...xxxxAxxxx..........
....xxxxxxx...........
.....xxxxx............
......xxx.............
.......x..............
......................
......................
```

Output of my code:

```
......................
......................
......................
.......x..............
......xxxx............
.....xxxxx............
....xxxxxxx...........
...xxxxAxxxx..........
....xxxxxxx...........
.....xxxxx............
......xxxx............
.......x..............
......................
......................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In testing out your code and doing some debugging, the point of contention is that the "for" loop that is to test and draw the "x" on the left half of the pattern actually does a test and acceptance for one of the positions on the right-hand side of the pattern and changes out the "." with an "x".

This is the "for" loop where this issue happens.

```
/* drawing range to the left side */
for (ran=0;ran<range;ran++){
    /* down */
    for(i=range;i>0;i--){
            if (matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] == '.'){
                matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
            }
            /* up */
            if (matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] == '.'){
                matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
```

When the value of "ran" is "3" and the value of "i" is 1, the resulting "x axis" position if "9" which is in the right-hand side of the pattern.

To not disrupt what the program is doing by attempting a rewrite of the loops, I refactored the tests within that "for" loop to insure that the testing pertains only to the left-hand side of the pattern as follows.

```
/* drawing range to the left side */
for (ran=0; ran<range; ran++)
{
    /* down */
    for(i=range; i>0; i--)
    {
        if (matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] == '.' && (ran - i < 0))
        {
            matrix[posy+ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
        }
        /* up */
        if (matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] == '.' && (ran - i < 0))
        {
            matrix[posy-ran][posx-i+ran] = 'x';
        }
    }
}
```

With that refactored code block, following was the output at the terminal.

```
@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Diamond/bin/Release$ ./Diamond 
......................
......................
......................
.......x..............
......xxx.............
.....xxxxx............
....xxxxxxx...........
...xxxxAxxxx..........
....xxxxxxx...........
.....xxxxx............
......xxx.............
.......x..............
......................
......................
```

As noted, there possibly other methods to use to correct the loop ranges, but sometimes a simple test revision is the most optimal solution.

Give this refactored code a try and see if it meets the spirit of your project.

Answer (score 0):

- You can simplify the calculation of the positions to fill with 'x'.
- It is not a good idea to embed magic numbers such as `22` and `14`
  in your code. Use `#define` instead.
- It will be better to pass parameters to the `draw_range()` function
  rather than declaring global variables.

Then would you please try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 22
#define HEIGHT 14
#define POSX 8
#define POSY 7
#define RANGE 4

void draw_range(char matrix[HEIGHT][WIDTH], int range, int posx, int posy) {
    int i, j, ofst;
    for (i = posy - range; i <= posy + range; i++) {
        ofst = (i - posy) > 0 ? (i - posy) : (posy - i);
        for (j = posx - range + ofst; j <= posx + range - ofst; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] == '.') {
                matrix[i][j] = 'x';
            }
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    int i, j;
    char matrix[HEIGHT][WIDTH];

    // fill array with spaces
    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT;i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }

    // put symbol to arrat
    matrix[POSY][POSX] = 'A';

    draw_range(matrix, RANGE, POSX, POSY);

    // print array
    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
            printf("%c", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```